# lapply functions inside each other does not work as expected

Tags: r

I have two lists and I must use `for` and `if` condition for my functions over these lists. I then decide to use `lapply` function. I used `lapply` function but my code becomes so difficult and do not work. How can I make my code work in an easy way. Is there a good way to do not use many `lapply` functions.

The idea of my code:

1. First have some lists.
2. These lists does not need to be all the same lengths or even all `> 0`.
3. So, my code check each list. if it is `> 0` or not.
4. If it is `> 0` then:
5. check the values of the second list.
6. If the values equal specific values then this values will changes to new values.

The last steps must applied to all the lists that I have.

Here is my code:

the function gave me `NULL`

```
nx <- list(1, 1) ## if my list  > 0 then check it
x.t <- list(c(2, 3, 4, 4), c(2, 4, 5, 6))  #the list to apply if statement on it. 

lapply(nx, function(x) if (x > 0) {
  do.t <-  lapply(x.t, function(x) { which(x %in% c(2, 7:10))})
  ##check the values of my list.

  lapply(nx, function(x){

  lapply(1:length(x), function(i){  for (j in 1:x[[i]]){ ## here I would like j from 1 to length of x where x is a list of two elements.

      if (x.t[[i]][do.t[[j]]] == 2) ## here I want to have a condition says that, if the element of each list is equal 2 then this element will have the value 2.5.
        x.t[[i]] <- 2.5
    }})})})
```

my function will includes many lists where the condition will be extend. For example,

```
    if (x.t[[i]][do.t[[j]]] == 2){
      x.t[[i]] <- 2.5
}else{ some condition}elese{other condtion}
```

and so on.

the result.

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]]
NULL


[[1]][[2]]
[[1]][[2]][[1]]
NULL



[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]]
NULL


[[2]][[2]]
[[2]][[2]][[1]]
NULL
```

My function is so complicated and hence I provide this example very similar to my original function.

Comment: You are using `i`without assigning any value to it.

Comment: Yes, but how to fix this problem. I used another `lapply` but does not work.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: I just would like to see that if my list is `>0` and then apply the condition based on that.

Comment: Do you want to change the values that are equal to 2 to 2.5?

Comment: yes, but my original function is complex than this. So, It must be like the example I provide.

Comment: I know there is an easy way to change the values. However, sometimes it is not easy like this. So, I wont it as general function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general function maybe it's better to divide the code into parts, each one doing just one thing.
Note that the `lapply` passes entire vectors, the elements of the list `x.t` to the function. Then, `complicated` loops through the elements of a vector, processing one at a time.

```
complicated <- function(x){
    for(i in seq_along(x)){
        if(x[i] > 0){
            if(x[i] == 2)
                x[i] <- 2.5
        }
    }
    x
}

x.t.2 <- lapply(x.t, function(x){
    x <- complicated(x)
    x
})

x.t.2
#[[1]]
#[1] 2.5 3.0 4.0 4.0
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 2.5 4.0 5.0 6.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. However, I must use `for` and` if` as I did. That because my function contains many lists and the values vary. That is, `x.t[[i]] <- 2.5` is only once case. However, I need to changes each value of my list.

Comment: @F.family OK, I will edit the answer to give a more complicated example.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help. Can I do then as one function. That because I have a wrapper function and I need to call values from these functions. Which will be complicated.

Comment: @F.family Yes, I believe you can. It is possible, even natural, to call functions from within functions. That's called structured programming :)